# Simple Mac Photo Management app

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, photos

I don't want a digital asset manager but rather I'm looking for a Mac app that has similar features of iPhoto/Picasa but let's me work at the file level instead of a separate database. I tried iPhoto '11 with the "Copy items to the iPhoto Library" unchecked which takes me most of the way there but what I would like is that when I change a photo, I want that change applied to the photo file instead of on a duplicate.  And I don't want to Export to the file to see changes to my photos files.  I have 1000s of photos already on my drive organized the way that I prefer and I would I would like the photo files on my drive to be the master copy.   I was used the "Windows Live Photo Gallery" app which provided core photo management and editing capabilities.  Is there something similar on the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Lyn](http://www.lynapp.com/) which definitely allows you to work at the file level within your existing folder structure. However, it's editing capabilities seem quite sparse compared to something like Picasa or iPhoto. There's a free trial, so it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

[Pixa](http://www.pixa-app.com/) looks like a new and fresh attempt at doing this well, and I am eager to throw out both iPhoto and Picasa.